# Übersetzung für "Someone great once said: ..."

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom

Ist "Wie einer der Großen sagte: ..." oder "Wie jemand von denen Großen sagte: ..." eine gute Übersetzung für "Someone great once said: ...", einen einleitenden Satz, wenn man einen berühmten Dichter, Philosoph oder Wissenschaftler zitieren möchte? Klingen beide etwas schräg und zu wörtlich übersetzt, aber vielleicht setzt bei mir bloß schon die Paranoia ein, zu wörtlich zu übersetzen...

Comment: Wenn eine berühmte Person zitiert werden soll, würde ich den Namen nennen: "Wie Kant einmal sagte: ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ein großer Geist sagte/meinte einst ...

Etwas arg poetisch, aber gebräuchlich ^^. Vor allem, wenn es für einen Dichter oder Philosophen genutzt wird.

Comment: Das klingt super, danke!

Comment: Alternativ auch ein *großer Denker*.

Answer (score 0):

Jemand Großartiges sagte einmal...

Comment: This feels a bit too verbatim, too much translated, so to speak. The alternatives shown in the other answer seem more natural to me.

Comment: Hm alright. I would say that in german. But I can understand that this doesnt sound elegant.